# Tag search for inclusion/exclusion with Rails will_paginate gem

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I need to return results based on a search of tags that allow for excluding tags by preceding them with a hyphen (i.e. "food, -water")

So far I have the tag search working with this in my Resource model:

```rb
resources = paginate(page: page, per_page: 30).where('tags.name IN (?)', tags).group('resource_id').having('COUNT(tags.id) = ?', tags.count).joins(:tags)
```

*tags* is an array of tags passed in the search terms and parsed with a regex pattern.

In order to remove the results that include "water" in them I am looping through the results and deleting them as follows:

```rb
resources.delete_if do |resource|
    (resource.tags.map(&:name) & exclude_tags).present?
  end
```

When using the will_paginate gem this creates an issue with the returned results. If I am asking for 30 results back and after retrieving those results 6 of them are deleted since they include the *excluded tag* (water) then the end result is the browser displaying 24 results instead of 30.

How can I accomplish this in the ActiveRecord query instead of deleting them after getting back the results?

Comment: isn't resources still an ActiveRelation after that line in your model?  Meaning that if this is what the controller or view is working with, the controller or view could do something like resources.where('tags.name NOT IN (?)', array_of_exclude_tags)

Comment: No it is not, resources is a will_paginate::collection class after that line in my model. All database transactions should be handled in the model, not passed to views or controller's to deal with.

Comment: i don't really know anything about the rest of your code, but if you want the exclude tags handled in the model then can't you just pass them in as an argument to the model method that composes resources and then add them to the where clause?